# Multiplication by $0$ in a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

#### Background

A field $\left( F,+,\cdot,0,1 \right)$ is an algebraic structure that is composed of  the two Abelian groups $\left( F,+,0 \right)$ and $\left( F \setminus \{ 0 \}, \cdot, 1 \right)$. The two distributive laws, which must hold, are irrelevant for what follows. I rather want to advert to the fact that multplication is a map
$$
F \setminus \{ 0 \} \times F \setminus \{ 0 \} \longrightarrow F \setminus \{ 0 \}.
$$

#### Question

Obviously, neither $(0,x)$ nor $(x,0)$ are in $F \setminus \{ 0 \} \times F \setminus \{ 0 \}$ and, therefore, elements of the domain of the multiplication. But doesn't this imply that expressions such as
$$
0 \cdot x = x \cdot 0 = 0
$$
cannot be written down, because multiplication by $0$ is acually impermissible?

---

#### Update

As the comments and answers clarify, the multiplication of a given field is, in fact, a map
$$
\cdot : F \times F \longrightarrow F,
$$
and the multiplication of the underlying multiplicative group is the restiction of $\cdot$ to $F \setminus \{ 0 \} \times F \setminus \{ 0 \}$ and would actually deserve another symbol.

My *false* reasoning was the other way round: Given two groups as above, a field is constructed by simply inheriting the addition and the multiplication.

Comment: Where did you get the definition that multiplication is a map $F\setminus\{0\}\times F\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow F\setminus\{0\}$? It's wrong. The point is that the restriction of the multiplication map $\cdot :F\times F\rightarrow F$ to the domain $F\setminus\{0\}\times F\setminus\{0\}$ forms a group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The multiplication $\cdot$ is a binary operation defined over *all* of $F$.

In particular, we can write $x\cdot 0$ and prove that it equals $0$.

When restricted to $F \setminus \{ 0 \}$, this multiplication defines a group structure.

Answer (score 1):

An arbitrary pair of elements of a field can be multiplied.